# Swift xcode how to add built in arrow

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, uitableview, user-interface

I have built a cell using 2 UIviews with a height of 1 in order to show up as a straight line. Between them I have placed a UILabel. So it looks just like a cell.

But by question now is how do I add an arrow to my label? I want the standard iOS label that shows up in cells.

Like this one that shows up as the "back" arrow when entering another view, but I want the thinner one

[image]

Thanks in advance,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This isn't exactly what you asked for, but it would probably be easier to download an image asset and use that instead. [icons8.com](http://icons8.com) and [flaticon.com](http://flaticon.com) are two very good websites that have tons of free icons.